# Firebase Cloud Functions onDelete problem - Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following structure in the Firebase database, where `RoomsTemplate` is a subscription room. If someone signs up for the `Users` node, another function (onWrite) increases the value of `CountUsers`.

[image]

and the following function decreases the value of `CountUsers` when users unsubscribe from node `Users`.

```
exports.recountUsers = functions.database.ref('/RoomsTemplate/{id}/CountUsers').onDelete(async (snap) => {
  const counterRef = snap.ref;
  const collectionRef = counterRef.parent.child('Users');
  const messagesData = await collectionRef.once('value');
  return await counterRef.set(messagesData.numChildren());
});
```

The problem is that, if I want to delete the main node of the `RoomsTemplate`, in this case

> -MBb2ZKj-pquagHBqguS

the `onDelete` function won't let me delete it, but it will update the `CountUsers: 0` again. Try deleting the `Barrio:"Barcelona"` node with another function first and then verify and delete the main node.

```
exports.recountUsers = functions.database.ref('/RoomsTemplate/{id}/CountUsers').onDelete(async (snap) => {
  const counterRef = snap.ref;
  const collectionRef = counterRef.parent.child('Users');  
  const messagesData = await collectionRef.once('value');

  const Barrio = await counterRef.parent.child('Barrio').once('value');

   if(Barrio.numChildren() === 0){
     return await counterRef.remove();
   }else if(Barrio.numChildren() > 0){
     return await counterRef.set(messagesData.numChildren());
   }else{
     return null;
   } 

});
```

But I still have the same existence problem. **How can I permanently delete the main node (-MBb2ZKj-pquagHBqguS), without executing the onDelete function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought is that you've modeled yourself into a problem here, by not following the guidance to keep your data structure flat. My recommended solution based on that is to further denormalize the data, and pull the counts into a separate top-level list. In fact, I see three top-level lists here:

```
RoomsTemplate
  $roomid: { Barrio: "..." }
},
RoomsTemplate_users: {
  $roomid: { "uid1" true, "uid2": true }
},
RoomsTemplate_usercounts: {
  $roomid: 2
}
```

Alternatively, within your current data structure, you can check if the room still exists before writing the counter. For example for the first Cloud Function that would look like:

```
exports.recountUsers = functions.database.ref('/RoomsTemplate/{id}/CountUsers').onDelete(async (snap) => {
  const counterRef = snap.ref;
  const roomRef = counterRef.parent;
  const roomSnapshot = await roomRef.once("value");
  if (roomSnapshot.exists()) {
    const messagesData = roomSnapshot.child("Users");
    await counterRef.set(messagesData.numChildren());
  }
  return true;
});
```

Since Cloud Functions execute asynchronously after the original write has completed, this `once('value'` (like the one you have for the `collectionRef` already) will always get the current snapshot from the database, which is where the room has disappeared.

Comment: Right! the problem here is that it never consults existence ... I added those conditions to the onWrite and onDelete function and voila! Thank you!